# processing data using weka PCA

Tags: java, weka, pca

I would like to do PCA for my dataset using weka's PCA.
I saw online the java code is:

1. PrincipalComponents pca = new PrincipalComponents();
2. pca.setMaximumAttributeNames(300);
3. pca.setInputFormat(Data);
4. Instances newData = Filter.useFilter(Data, pca);

I import both import weka.attributeSelection.PrincipalComponents and import weka.filters.Filter in the code, but eclipse always shows that in the third line, pca need to be cast to Filter. After I cast pca to Filter, it is still wrong. The fourth line is also showed wrong. I would like to know what is the right code to do pca for an existing dataset?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that there are two classes called `PrincipalComponents` in the weka API:

`weka.attributeSelection.PrincipalComponents` and `weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.PrincipalComponents`.

The latter is a kind of `Filter`, but you are importing the former, which is not.

Just change your import statement and your code should work.

Comment: Yes, I saw the same thing as you saw. But why so many online materials using these lines of code to do pca?   http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/how-to-do-Principal-Component-Analysis-in-java-code-for-both-TrainData-and-TestData-td23269.html

Comment: I just figured it out and updated my answer accordingly.